# Mockito fails for Spring data JPA Page interface

Tags: spring-data-jpa, mockito

```
@SpringBootTest
public class TestClass {

    @Mock
    private Page<Customer> pagedResult;

    @Mock
    private Pageable paging = PageRequest.of(0, 1);

    @Mock
    private CustomerRepository cutomerRepository;

    @InjectMocks
    private CustomerServiceImpl service;

    @Test
    void testss() {
        Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
        set.add(1);
        Pageable paging1 = PageRequest.of(0, 1);
        Page<Customer> pa = new PageImpl<>(Arrays.asList(customer));
        when(cutomerRepository.findByIdIn(set, paging1)).thenReturn(pa);
        when(service.test(set)).thenReturn(Arrays.asList(customer));
        assertEquals(customer.getName(), service.test(set).get(0).getgetName());
    }
}
```

Implementation class

```
public class CustomerServiceImpl {

    private CustomerRepository customerRepository ;

    public CustomerServiceImpl(CustomerRepository customerRepository ) {
        super();
        this.customerRepository = customerRepository ;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Customer> test(Set<Integer> ids) {
        Pageable paging = PageRequest.of(0, 1);
        Page<Customer> pagedResult = customerRepository.findByIdIn(ids, paging);
        return pagedResult.toList();
    }
}
```

I am trying to write the Junit test case for my pagination code using mockito but it fails as it is expecting the return type for method as Page.but I am returning List of Customers.When I return Page from method it works fine but if I return List is fails with below mentioned error

**I am getting below error**

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.WrongTypeOfReturnValue: 
ArrayList cannot be returned by findByIdIn()
findByIdIn() should return Page
```

If you're unsure why you're getting above error read on.
Due to the nature of the syntax above problem might occur because:

1. This exception *might* occur in wrongly written multi-threaded tests.
   Please refer to Mockito FAQ on limitations of concurrency testing.
2. A spy is stubbed using when(spy.foo()).then() syntax. It is safer to stub spies -
   with doReturn|Throw() family of methods. More in javadocs for Mockito.spy() method.

Comment: `CustomerServiceImpl` contains `DoctorRepository doctorRepository` so `TestClass` has to have `@Mock DoctorRepository doctorRepository`. But it has  `@Mock CustomerRepository cutomerRepository` instead. What purpose of `pagedResult` and `paging` mocks?

Comment: Sorry,I had pasted incorrect code.I have corrected it now.
Mock for pagedResult and paging  was not working so created them in method but even that is not working.

Pageable paging1 = PageRequest.of(0, 1);
Page<Customer> pa = new PageImpl<>(Arrays.asList(customer));

Answer (score 0):

I think something is messed with your code.
In Your code you have `doctorRepository.findByIdIn` Method bt in your test class it is `cutomerRepository.findByIdIn`.

I have added the below code as a reference with respect to your `CustomerServiceImpl`.
You can try the same way to execute your test.

```
SpringBootTest
public class TestClass {
    
    @Mock
    private Pageable paging;

    @Mock
    private CustomerRepository cutomerRepository;
    
    @Mock
    private DoctorRepository doctorRepository;

    @InjectMocks
    private CustomerServiceImpl service;

    @Test
    void testss() {
    
        Doctor doctor = new Doctor();
        doctor.setName("test name");
         
        Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
        set.add(1);
        
        PageImpl<Doctor> page = new PageImpl<>(Arrays.asList(doctor));
        when(doctorRepository.findByIdIn(Mockito.any(), Mockito.any())).thenReturn(page);
        
        List<Doctor> doctors= service.test(set);
        
        assertEquals(doctor.getName(), doctors.get(0).getgetName());
    }
}
```